# Fingerprint SDK for Linux

Tags: linux, fingerprint, biometrics

Please tell me is there any SDK for fingerprints developed in Java or C/C++ that can be used on Linux platform?

Regards.
Mukul Gupta

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [NIST Biometric Image Software (NBIS) package](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm) which includes the BOZORTH3 fingerprint matching algorithm. It's not an SDK per se but it does let you compare fingerprints on Linux. See also the [NBIS User Guide](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=51097) and the [download link](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

yes Tutis Technologies developed such type of [Software Development Kit(SDK)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110426032304/http://www.tutistech.in/fingerprint_software_development_kits.html) which can be used in Linux Platform.